# Отключение элемента после прокрутки с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть меню на сайте (`<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">`) и изначально оно скрыто. Пользователь может открывать/заркывать меню нажатием кнопки. Допустим, пользователь открыл меню, мне необходимо:

1. Если пользователь прокрутил страницу на 100px в любую сторону, надо закрыть меню.
2. Если пользователь щёлкнул в любом месте страницы за пределами блока меню - закрыть меню.

Как показывать меню после прокрутки я разобрался. Но как его скрывать после прокрутки определённого количества пикселей пока не могу понять. Как я понимаю, мне надо хранить в переменной сколько прокручено пикселей. Далее мне надо обнулять эту переменную если пользователь не скролит мышкой допустим 5 секунд. Как тогда понять что пользователь на данный момент не скролит?

```js
<script>
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            var pixelCount = window.pageYOffset;
            if (pixelCount < 300) {document.getElementById("hmt").checked = false;}
            if (pixelCount > 300) {document.getElementById("hmt").checked = true;}
        })
</script>
```

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы меню скрывалось всегда если пользователь проскролил определённое количество пикселей. К примеру пользователь открыл меню, потом начал скролить - меню закрылось. Дальше пользователь опять открыл меню, опять начал скролить - меню опять должно закрыться чтобы не висеть и не закрывать контент.

Comment: Да, меню зафикировано в правом углу экрана.

Comment: Я большой новичок в JS. А как в таком случае брать значение скрола? Пробую const example = window.pageYOffset, но значение меняется.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q. Что-то у меня не получается получить фиксированное число. https://codepen.io/gorenkov/pen/vYYEXvV

Comment: У меня эти переменные показывают одно и то же значение.

Comment: какой у Вас браузер?

Comment: Основной - Safari, а вообще все основные установлены тоже

Comment: Я тут в документации ковыряюсь, window.scrollY и window.pageYOffset - это одно и тоже. window.pageYOffset - более новая версия и работает во всех браузерах.

Comment: Я не могу понять как мне создать константу и положить в неё значение скрола когда была нажата галка. Чтобы потом сравнить с текущим положением скрола. Даже если я создаю константу, то при скроле её значение всё равно меняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот собрал Вам пример, как бы я это сделал:

```js
let opened;

function openMenu() {
  opened = window.scrollY
  nav.classList.add('visible')
}

addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  if (Math.abs(opened - pageYOffset ) > 300)
    nav.classList.remove('visible')    
})

addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.id !== 'nav' && e.target.id !== 'btn')
    nav.classList.remove('visible')
})
```

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
section {
  height:1000px;
}
button, nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
nav {
  background: wheat;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center
}

.visible{
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<button id=btn onclick=openMenu() >open menu</button>
<nav id=nav>scroll 300 px away to hide menu</nav>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Супер, всё получилось! Немного переделал под себя. Огромное спасибо за помощь!